# run a FOR loop to create 4 plumbers from the default constructor c#

Tags: c#

As you see in the title above, i need to run a FOR loop to create 4 plumbers from the default constructor. After they are created (within the FOR loop), change their names, add them to the employee list and display in listbox. So basically, plumbers is actually a list declared in another class called EmployeeList. Wehn i tried changing their names to random ones, i get like an error msg saying 'Index is out of range'. Can someone help me with this?

**Form Code**

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //create class-level employee list 
    EmployeeList plumbers = new EmployeeList();

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //run a for loop to create 4 plumbers from the default constructor.
        for (int i = 0; i < plumbers.Count; i++)
            plumbers[i] = new Employee();

        //After they are created (within the FOR loop), change their names, 
        //plumbers[0].Name = "Nicole Fernandez";

        //add them to the employee list  

        //display in listbox
        foreach (Employee item in plumbers.Employees)
        { 
            lstDisplay.Items.Add(item.DisplayData());
        }
    }
```

**Employee List Class Code**

```
class EmployeeList
{
    //use private access modifier to create a list of employee
    private List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>();

    public List<Employee> Employees
    {
        get { return employees; }
        set { employees = value; }
    }

    //return the count of the employee list, use lambda operator
    public int Count => employees.Count();

    //create default constructor
    public EmployeeList() { }

    //create a method that adds employee sent to the list. No return value
    public void AddEmp(Employee emp)
    {
        employees.Add(emp);//add employee to the list
    } 

    //create employee from data sent. No return value
    public void AddEmp(string inName, int inID, decimal inHourlyWage)
    {
        //declare a variable
        Employee emp = new Employee(inName, inID, inHourlyWage);
        //call the other AddEmp
        AddEmp(emp);
    }

    //create a method that deletes employee from the list. No return value
    public void DeleteEmp(Employee emp) => employees.Remove(emp);

    //insert employee at the index
    public void InsertEmp(Employee emp, int index) => employees.Insert(index, emp);

    //create an indexer
    public Employee this[int i]
    { //q12 - indexer property with exception
        get
        {
            if (i < 0 || i >= Count)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(i.ToString());
            return employees[i];
        }
        set { employees[i] = value; }
    }

}
```

**Employee Class Code**

```
class Employee
{
    //use auto-implemented property
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public decimal HourlyWage { get; set; }
    public decimal TotalPay { get; set; }

    //create static integer that starts at 1
    private static int NextID = 1;

    //create a default constructor with default values
    public Employee()
    {
        ID = NextID++;
        Name = "John Doe";
        HourlyWage = 15.25m;
        TotalPay = 0.0m;
    }

    //create the custom constructor sending in 3 parameters
    public Employee(string inName, int inID, decimal inHourlyWage)
    {
        Name = inName;//set name, no validation is required

        //validate ID is between 1 and 250. if not, set to nextID available
        if (inID <= 1 && inID >= 250)
            NextID = inID;

        //validate hourly wage is between 12.50 and 20. If not, set to 15.25
        if (inHourlyWage <= 12.50m && inHourlyWage >= 20.0m)
            inHourlyWage = 15.25m;

        TotalPay = 0;//set total pay to 0
    }

    public string DisplayData() => ID + "\t" + Name + "\t" + HourlyWage.ToString("c") + "\t" + TotalPay.ToString("c");
}
```

Comment: The list is empty when you get to the first `for`. Count is zero, so `for` won't execute. Next statement tries to access a non-existent element, because again, the list is empty.

Comment: @MarkLarter so how do i execute it, as what the question says, i have to run a for loop that creates 4 plumbers and change their names after that..

Comment: See answer. You just need to make the loop that is going to add the items run a fixed number of times, rather than using the limit as the Count which is going to be zero at start.

Comment: You have a bug where you are comparing your hourly wage - You need to change the `&&` to `||`, because a wage will never be less that 12.5 AND greater than 20. It could, however, be one OR the other. (Same with the `inID` comparison)

Comment: @RufusL i am trying to say that its between 12.5 and 20.0..do i still have to change the || operator?

Comment: @NicoleFernandez Yes. Because what you're really saying is that if it's NOT between 12.5 and 20.0 then you want to change it. That's where it gets tricky. Try reading it out loud... "If the hourly wage is less than to 12.5 AND the houly wage is greater than 20.0 then it should be 15.25." The hourly wage will NEVER be both less than 12.5 AND greater than 20.0. You would instead say, "If the hourly wage is less than 12.5 OR the hourly wage is more than 20.0 then it should be 15.25."

Comment: Your `EmployeeList` is not a `List`. It contains a `List` called `employees`, and you even wrote a method to add an employee. So, you should be adding items to the `List`, using `plumbers.AddEmp(new Employee())`.

Comment: @RufusL do i do that in loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if you want to create a list of 4 plumbers using a loop, then you need the loop to iterate 4 times. This is normally done by setting the initial counter value to 0, then looping while it is less than the number you want:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

Also, your `plumbers` object is of type `EmployeeList`, but you're trying to access it with an indexer as if it's a `List` or an `Array`. Instead, you should use the method you created to add new employees:

```
// Run a for loop to create 4 plumbers from the default constructor.
for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
{
    plumbers.AddEmp(new Employee());
}
```

Since there doesn't appear to be any public method to update an existing plumber, we can just access the `Employees` list directly to rename the plumbers. There are a couple of ways to do it. One would be to use a loop and use part of the loop counter in the name:

```
// After they are created (within the FOR loop), change their names 
for(int i = 0; i < plumbers.Employees.Count; i++)
{
    plumbers.Employees[i].Name = string.Format("Plumber #{0}", i); 
}
```

Another way is to do it by hand, giving each plumber a normal name:

```
plumbers.Employees[0].Name = "Nicole";
plumbers.Employees[1].Name = "Rufus";
plumbers.Employees[2].Name = "Mark";
plumbers.Employees[3].Name = "John";
```

Or, if you want to be really fancy, you can generate a list of names (I pulled these from [the top baby names of 2016](http://www.goodhousekeeping.com/life/parenting/news/a37824/popular-baby-names-2016/)), then for each plumber grab a random name from the list and assign it (and remove it from the list so the plumbers all have unique names):

```
//After they are created (within the FOR loop), change their names 

// Generate a list names
var nameCandidates = new List<string>
{
    "Olivia", "Amelia", "Charlotte", "Ava", "Isla", "Arabella", "Aurora",
    "Adeline", "Penelope", "Eleanor", "Ezra", "Asher", "Atticus",
    "Declan", "Oliver", "Silas", "Milo", "Levi", "Henry", "Wyatt"
};

// Loop through each plumber and choose a random name
var rnd = new Random();
foreach(var plumber in plumbers.Employees)
{
    // Choose a random name, assign it, and remove it from candidates
    var nameIndex = rnd.Next(nameCandidates.Count);
    plumber.Name = nameCandidates[nameIndex];
    nameCandidates.RemoveAt(nameIndex);
}
```